# Net 6 nullable not giving warning for all types

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-6.0, c#-10.0

Using Net 6's `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` I have the class:

```
public class File {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public Byte[] Content { get; set; }
  public DateTime Created { get; set; }
  public Guid Key { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
  
  public FileType FileType { get; set; }
}
```

Why do I get the warning

```
Non-nullable property '...' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the property as nullable.
```

in all properties but not in:

```
Int32 Id
DateTime Created
Guid Key
```

Comment: That warning only applies to reference types. The feature is called "nullable ***reference*** types". Those properties are value types.

Comment: `Int32`, `DateTime`, and `Guid` are structs and cannot be null.

Comment: An `Int32` (or more commonly, int)  can never be null. Its default value is 0. If you wanted to store a `null` to `Id` you'd have to change its type to `int?` which is shorthand for `Nullable<int>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nullable reference types only affect reference types. Value types can never be null and so there is no need to check or warn against them being null.